# Should I Use useMemo to Wrap Components Delivered as Props in React Composition Pattern?

Tags: reactjs, composition, rerender

Our React project has a code written in Composition Pattern as below.

```
return (
  <Template
    title={
      useMemo(
        () => (
         <>
           <TitleComponent prop={value} />
           <TitleComponent prop={value} />
         </>
         ),
        [deps]
      )
    }
  />
)
```

I didn't apply useMemo to TitleComponent at first. According to [this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/optimize-react-re-renders), I thought it would be optimized just by delivering components to prop.

However, my colleague argues that it is better to use useMemo because if you apply useMemo, you can skip the render phase. Otherwise, he claim that only the commit phase is skipped.

1. Is it true that render phase runs if useMemo is not used in the code above?
2. Is it useful to wrap prop components in useMemo?

- I editted my code. There were multiple components wrapped with fragment in prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to answer your questions since I think you're confused on what really is the purpose of that hook. Instead I'll give you a better understanding on it.

`useMemo` is used when you have a very heavy computation inside a component. What that hook does is, it takes a state/props as dependencies and it wont re-execute the computations unless those dependencies change. Meaning if you have a component that does very heavy computations on render that causes your app to slow down, you need to wrap the computation inside a `useMemo` to prevent recomputing your heavy calculations during rerender. In your case, do you have heavy computation on that title component? Absolutely NOT. So you are using that hook wrong.

What you need is `React.memo`. This one will convert your component into `PureComponent` which will skip unnecessary rerenders if your component only displays static content that doesn't change.

Comment: this is the correct answer. useMemo is for skipping recalculation of data if dependencies didn't change, not for skipping re-creation of react elements. Otherwise you would just wrap every react element in a memo

Comment: Actually useMemo can be used instead of React.memo. One example is: if the things it depends are not passed as props. He is not using it to just prevent calculation of React.createElement, he is using it to stop rerendering of the component since it keeps its reference. And then it will be skipped from the diffing algorithm

Comment: @OktayYuzcan you cant use useMemo instead of React.memo, at the very least because useMemo is a hook (used inside a component, called every render) and React.memo is just a function that is called outside of component, once, when javascript is executed

Comment: @OktayYuzcan Regarding diffing algorithm: it looks only at the type of rendered elements (e.g. <a> vs <span>, <ComponentA> vs <ComponentB>), it literally doesn't care whether the reference to a fragment (<> </>) that wraps those elements, changes. Think how every render always creates new "references" to all elements, that would make diffing algo useless. Also, don't confuse passing props and re-rendering with work of diffing algo - these are two separate processes happening at a different time (one before and another after render)

Comment: İ explained it in my answer. Render happens when the type of the element is different. But re-render happens when the reference from React.createElement is different. When the diffing algorithm encounters same reference from createElement it skips the comparison. This is what he is doing with useMemo here, keeps the instance of <></>. Without useMemo here the diffing algorithm sees createElement(Fragment) !== createElement(Fragment) (by reference) and it re-renders. With useMemo: const instance = useMemo(() => <></>,[]) and instance === instance (it is same between renders) and skips rerender

Comment: And yes, you can use useMemo instead of React.memo. You can't use it outside of the component, but İ didn't say they are used the same way. İ said it can do the same job as React.memo. at the end React.memo is doing something like useMemo under the hood. Probably currently it uses shouldComponentUpdate, but you can create your own version of React.memo using HOC and useMemo

Comment: Check this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ipc475?file=src%2FApp.js  .  In the example you can not use React.memo if the component does not need that dependency value as prop. Check the console. The second component rerenders only when its dependency changes. At the end it can do the same job as React.memo

Answer (score 0):

firstly, if you want to memoize component with `useMemo`, it is useful if it takes time to rerender, otherwise it won't change anything.

If you don't use it:

- If the `Template` component rerenders, the `title` wont
- If the Parent component that returns `Template` rerenders, the `title` and `Template` will rerender as well

If you use it:

- If the `Template` component rerenders, the `title` wont
- If the Parent component that returns `Template` rerenders, the `Template` will rerender as well, but the `title` will rerender only if there is difference in the dependency array

This thing `<Component ... />` returns an object (React calls `createElement` and it returns an object).

- **Render** happens when the Component is different than the previous Component.
- **Rerender** happens when the returned object from `React.createElement` is different (by reference) than the other one from previous render

Check this example (In the Console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ipc475?file=src%2FApp.js  The component that is inside useMemo rerenders only if there are any changes in the dependency array

Answer (score -1):

Is always nice to try using `useMemo`.

What it does: It memoize your component/data and rerender when any variable of the dependencies array changes. So when any other state variable changes react will not have to rerender this memoized component improving performance.

Some use cases are:

- When you have a heavy calculation in your component or variable
- To prevent refetch same data in APIs

Here's a little example of how to use it:

```
const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState<string>('abc')
const [myOtherVar, setMyOtherVar] = useState<number>(123)

return useMemo(() => (<>

  <div>Memoized: { myVar }</div>

  <div> Not memoized: {myOtherVar} </div>

</>),[myVar])
```

What is it doing here?

When you change `myVar` value using `setMyVar` react will rerender the component to update it's content in dom.

But if you change `myOtherVar` value with `setMyOtherVar` react will not rerender the component and it's value will not be updated in dom.

PS: If you change `myOtherVar` and after this you change `myVar` both values will be updated in dom because the rerender was done after updating the unmemoized variable so react will take all updated values of all variables.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usememo-example-tvkngc)'s a simple codesandbox working example

Comment: there's no improving performance in your examples, only creating sources of bugs and unreadable code. And confusing author even more (`return useMemo(...)` ?). Also, useMemo doesn't memoize neither component nor data. You shouldn't try to "help" React by memoizing react elements - memoize functions that calculate data instead, or components with React.memo

Comment: As you can read this is a `simple example` to help him understand what useMemo does. Deep learning of useMemo (and any other react hooks) and knowledge of how and when use it takes a long time and it's not a stackoverflow question that will skip this process. I answered this with the same content that makes me understand useMemo when I was learning it. The most basic use of it is this